# SQL can't group by... Options?

Tags: sql, select, oracle9i

I have the next tables:
involved_in represents a relation between a movie and a person who worked in it:

```
     FID        AID   JOB
 ---------- ---------- -----------------------------------
   2387816     226673 actor
   2146284     230306 actor
   1814529     233362 actor
   2146710     275818 actor
   2033140     324419 actor
   2387816     452297 actor
   1749641     522815 actor
   2379685     972581 actor
   2384487    1001930 actor
   2065098    1021573 actor
```

is_a represents a relation between two movies as in movie a is a prequel to movie b:

```
   MOVID1     MOVID2     REL_ID
  ---------- ---------- ----------
  2455766    1858631          2
  2465356     716238         12
  2465467    1005316          2
  2465585    2046499          1
  2465793    1992318          6
  2465793    2144984          5
  2467514    1984530         15
```

In other tables I can get titles and names for the id's used above.

I want to find those pairs actor-director that have worked more than x times together in movies that are not related as in Johnny Depp has worked with Tim Burton in movies that are not related.

The problem comes with the x times and my really small database account which won't let me have big enough temp tables.
I can:

```
create view friends as
(select actor, director, film, count(*) over (PARTITION BY actor, director) as together
from
(select a.aid as actor, b.aid as director, a.fid as film
from involved_in a, involved_in b
where a.fid=b.fid AND (a.job='actor' or a.job='actress') AND b.job='director'));
```

And that will give me every actor-director pair, every film they've worked in together and how many times they have worked together.

The view is too big so I could start by removing all those pairs that have worked less than x times together. Using group by actor, director gets me an error in film (not a group by expression).

Is there any way to limit the rows that appear with count less than x? I've also tried

```
having count(...) > x
```

It would be perfect if I could  count(actor, director) but that's not the syntax of course since it would be convenient.

After getting my friends view I'm using this query:

```
select f1.actor, f1.director
from friends f1, friends f2, is_a
where f1.actor = f2.director and f2.actor = f1.director and NOT (f1.film = movid1 and f2.film = movid2);
```

I don't use `JOIN ON` and such because my teacher said they were redundant though I do think it looks better so maybe I will use them eventually.

Any ideas?

Comment: my best advice to you is to **change your teacher.** explicit joins are a part of ansi sql for over 20 years now. if your teacher is not aware of that what other things is he not aware of?

Comment: He is aware of them and he told us we could use them if we wanted to but since it's the same... I don't know, the guy is a good teacher.

Comment: You should fix the question.  Your sample data, text, and query don't refer to the same tables.

Comment: I dont see where, Gordon

Comment: Also, what is your final goal? What do you really want to know from the data in your database? If it's the names of the actor / director pair and the number of unrelated films they worked on together

Comment: Just the names or their id's is fine. The final query I edited would give me what I want if it could run (I think). I'd need a more efficient way now I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following query, with some major tweaks to yours and removed redundancy.

Use explicit `JOINs` for better readability, and `IN` clause to save some space in code. Planner will translate this clause anyways.

```
CREATE VIEW friends AS
SELECT
    actor, director, film, num_together
FROM(
    SELECT
        a.aid AS actor,
        b.aid AS director,
        a.fid AS film,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.aid, b.aid) AS num_together
    FROM
        involved_in a
        INNER JOIN involved_in b ON
            a.fid = b.fid
    WHERE
        a.job IN ('actor', 'actress')
        AND b.job = 'director'
    ) foo
WHERE
    num_together < 'x' -- placeholder for your "limit the rows that appear with count less than x"
```

Though, this view may be misleading, as it lists the number of times which actor and director worked together, but it appears right next to every film they did work on together.

Comment: You are correct, the MiddleQuery in my answer is redundant. I can't believe I've missed that...

Comment: I can create the view but when I select it I instantly get a ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
My db account is indeed poor :(

Answer (score 1):

You already have nested select statements, just add another one:

```
create view friends as
(
SELECT actor, director, film, together
FROM (
      select actor, director, film, count(*) over (PARTITION BY actor, director) as together
      from
           (
           select a.aid as actor, b.aid as director, a.fid as film
           from involved_in a 
           INNER JOIN involved_in b ON(a.fid=b.fid)
           WHERE (a.job='actor' or a.job='actress') 
           AND b.job='director'
           ) InnerMostQuey
     ) MiddleQuery
WHERE together > x -- Replace x with whatever number that makes you happy :-)
);
```

Comment: This view I could create and select *. But when I run the next select (which I will edit now in the question) it won't stop or give any error messages (after a long while it does).